# AngularJs and global namespace

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm working on a project that requires us to embed our AngularJS application to other websites. The application currently uses requireJs to load AngularJS. However, the current AngularJS attach the angular object to window and this can potentially cause conflict with other websites using their own version of AngularJS.
I wonder if there's away we can manually place these the angular object into a specific namespace without breaking the code.

Comment: any luck on this? I am running into the same scenario you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DrewSamsen Using the solution in the below answer worked for me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try renaming following in the source:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js

```
   /** @name angular */
    angular           = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),
```

To something custom:

```
   /** @name angular */
    angular           = window.angularX || (window.angularX = {}),
```

And then use renamed version in your code: `angularX`.

Comment: I tried to do something similar, but further down, angular is being referenced somewhere from window to setup the core functions like module() and copy(), which will not appear if you do so.